# Why are we dividing the the difference of dates by 1000?

Tags: javascript

```
var newYear = "1 jan 2022";

function countDates() {
  var newYearDate = new Date(newYear);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  const days = Math.floor((newYearDate - currentDate) / (1000*60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((newYearDate - currentDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((newYearDate - currentDate) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((newYearDate - currentDate) / 1000);
  console.log(days, hours, minutes,seconds);
}

countDates();
```

In this code I have substracted the initialized(NewYearDate) date with the current date and tried to get days, hours, minutes out of it, I got the logic on the internet but can't understand why it is divided by 1000 for all the variables (days, hours, minutes).

Comment: just to clarify @Barmar 's comment, dates are stored `internally` as a long value of milliseconds past 12AM Jan 1 1970 GMT

Comment: you should use the [proper methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods), as calculating things based on constants won't always yield the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when Date is converted to a number the value is in **milliseconds**
1 second === 1000 milliseconds

Comment: Don't you think `1 second === 1000 milliseconds` should have been `1 second = 1000 milliseconds`? Are you comparing or denoting?

Comment: @Chilarai It's describing an equivalence, not assigning or comparing anything.